# On-click go to dynamic url with id reference solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have an array in JavaScript as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var array1 = Array(0,1,2,3,4,5);
</script>
```

I have six table cells (`<td>`s) as follows:

```
<td class="title" id="title1">
<td class="title" id="title2">
<td class="title" id="title3">
<td class="title" id="title4">
<td class="title" id="title5">
<td class="title" id="title6">
```

I need an `onclick` go to URL solution. As you can see, The cells have 6 ids, from title1 to title6. The cell have to first look for its corresponding values in the array.. (`0` for `title1`, `1` for `title2` etc..). The corresponding values, as you can see is calculated using `array[titlenumber-1]`. If corresponding array number is greater than 0, the page may go to `www.example.com` when user click the `<td>` and if the number is less than or equal to 0, the page may alert the user "DATA ERROR". How can I do this using JavaScript and jQuery?

Comment: While someone else may be able to give you a good answer (I can't), I would advise **against** clickable `td`s, as they will not be accessible for web crawlers. Links are specified with `a` tag, and `onclick` should really be used for client-side stuff like sending AJAX requests, changing DOM, etc. **And I beg you not to display “DATA ERROR” in an alert.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
var array1 = Array(0,1,2,3,4,5);

$('td').click(function(){

    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var index = parseInt(id.substr(5, id.length), '10');//take off title
    index -= 1;
    if (array1[index] > 0){
        window.location = 'www.example.com';
    }else{
        alert("data error");
    }

});
```

I've created [this](http://jsfiddle.net/keQDb/3/) fiddle and it works (if you click on "a" you get an aler, otherwise it redirects to example.com )